# Swift 5: Non-terrible solutions for sharing of JSON Key-values for Codable Structs?

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct, codable

Being a fan of value types and pure functions I let all my models be structs. But some of my models share properties that I need to JSON encode. Since I cannot use inheritance (mostly good, but in this case bad, but I still wanna stick to structs) I need to declare these properties each struct. But Swift's `Codable` does not allow for

Using Swift 5.1, is there any elegant solution (as in avoiding code duplication and retorting to `NSJSONSerialization` and dictionary hacks) for sharing JSON key values for structs? Especially when encoding `struct`s.

Simple example

```swift
protocol SerializableModel: Codable {
    static var version: Int { get }
    static var serializerName: String { get }
}

extension SerializableModel {
    // Default value
    static var version: Int { 100 }

    // Static -> Instance convenience
    var version: Int { Self.version }
    var serializerName: String { Self.serializerName }
}

enum SharedCodingKeyValues {}
extension SharedCodingKeyValues {
    static let version = "version"
    static let serializer = "serializer"
}

struct Person {
    let name: String
}

extension Person: SerializableModel {
    static var serializerName: String = "com.mycompany.person"
}

// MARK: Encodable
extension Person {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        // Does not even compile: `Cannot invoke 'encode' with an argument list of type '(Int, forKey: String)'`
//        try container.encode(version, forKey: SharedCodingKeyValues.version)

        // Runtime crash: => `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`
//        try container.encode(version, forKey: CodingKeys.init(stringValue: SharedCodingKeyValues.version)!)
//        try container.encode(serializerName, forKey: CodingKeys.init(stringValue: SharedCodingKeyValues.serializer)!)
    }
}
```

Bah! Okay so that did not work, currently, I have surrendered to this solution which I'm unhappy with:

```swift
struct Person {
    let name: String
}

extension Person: SerializableModel {
    static var serializerName: String = "com.mycompany.person"
}

// MARK: CodingKeys
extension Person {

    // Uh, terrible! I REALLY do not wanna do this, because for large models with many stored properties I have to declare ALL my
    // JSON keys, even if they are unchanged (waiting for Swift to improve specifically this point)
    // Also since just be declaring this, auto-synthesizing of `init(from decoder: Decoder)` stopped working, uhh! This is terrible.
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name

        // Does not even compile: `Raw value for enum case must be a literal`
//        case serializer = SharedCodingKeyValues.serializer

        case serializer // uh, terrible, the name of this enum has to match ALL my other models' CodingKeys.serializer value, and if the JSON key changes server side I need to find and update them all, since I cannot share this value
        case version
    }
}

// MARK: Encodable
extension Person {

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        try container.encode(version, forKey: .version)
        try container.encode(serializerName, forKey: .serializer)
    }
}

// MARK: Decodable
extension Person {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        // Actually for now we don't care about any incoming values for the keys `version` and `serializerName` has already been used elsewhere
    }
}
```

So many things about this solution is bad, read the comments inlined with the code.

## How can we do better?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is define a custom `CodingKey` that essentially combines both your model's coding keys and any other coding keys you want, like so (warning - there's a lot of code here, but I made it so it's generic enough to be reusable for any model in any project):

```swift
protocol CompoundableCodingKey: CodingKey {
    associatedtype OtherCodingKeys1
    associatedtype OtherCodingKeys2

    init(otherCodingKeys1: OtherCodingKeys1)
    init(otherCodingKeys2: OtherCodingKeys2)
    init(intValue: Int)
    init(stringValue: String)
}

struct CompoundCodingKeys<OtherCodingKeys1: CodingKey, OtherCodingKeys2: CodingKey>: CompoundableCodingKey {
    private let otherCodingKeys1: OtherCodingKeys1?
    private let otherCodingKeys2: OtherCodingKeys2?
    private let internalIntValue: Int?
    private let internalStringValue: String

    var intValue: Int? {
        if let otherCodingKeys1 = otherCodingKeys1 {
            return otherCodingKeys1.intValue
        } else if let otherCodingKeys2 = otherCodingKeys2 {
            return otherCodingKeys2.intValue
        }

        return internalIntValue
    }

    var stringValue: String {
        if let otherCodingKeys1 = otherCodingKeys1 {
            return otherCodingKeys1.stringValue
        } else if let otherCodingKeys2 = otherCodingKeys2 {
            return otherCodingKeys2.stringValue
        }

        return internalStringValue
    }

    init(intValue: Int) {
        if let otherCodingKeys1 = OtherCodingKeys1(intValue: intValue) {
            self.otherCodingKeys1 = otherCodingKeys1
            otherCodingKeys2 = nil
            internalIntValue = nil
            internalStringValue = otherCodingKeys1.stringValue
        } else if let otherCodingKeys2 = OtherCodingKeys2(intValue: intValue) {
            otherCodingKeys1 = nil
            self.otherCodingKeys2 = otherCodingKeys2
            internalIntValue = nil
            internalStringValue = otherCodingKeys2.stringValue
        } else {
            otherCodingKeys1 = nil
            otherCodingKeys2 = nil
            internalIntValue = intValue
            internalStringValue = intValue.description
        }
    }

    init(stringValue: String) {
        if let otherCodingKeys1 = OtherCodingKeys1(stringValue: stringValue) {
            self.otherCodingKeys1 = otherCodingKeys1
            otherCodingKeys2 = nil
            internalIntValue = nil
            internalStringValue = otherCodingKeys1.stringValue
        } else if let otherCodingKeys2 = OtherCodingKeys2(stringValue: stringValue) {
            otherCodingKeys1 = nil
            self.otherCodingKeys2 = otherCodingKeys2
            internalIntValue = nil
            internalStringValue = otherCodingKeys2.stringValue
        } else {
            otherCodingKeys1 = nil
            otherCodingKeys2 = nil
            internalIntValue = nil
            internalStringValue = stringValue
        }
    }

    init(otherCodingKeys1: OtherCodingKeys1) {
        self.init(stringValue: otherCodingKeys1.stringValue)
    }

    init(otherCodingKeys2: OtherCodingKeys2) {
        self.init(stringValue: otherCodingKeys2.stringValue)
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol where Key: CompoundableCodingKey {
    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encode(value, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encode(value, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeConditional<T>(_ object: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: AnyObject, T: Encodable {
        try encodeConditional(object, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeConditional<T>(_ object: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: AnyObject, T: Encodable {
        try encodeConditional(object, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol where Key: CompoundableCodingKey, Key.OtherCodingKeys1: CompoundableCodingKey {
    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encode(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encode(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeConditional<T>(_ object: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: AnyObject, T: Encodable {
        try encodeConditional(object, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeConditional<T>(_ object: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: AnyObject, T: Encodable {
        try encodeConditional(object, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol where Key: CompoundableCodingKey, Key.OtherCodingKeys2: CompoundableCodingKey {
    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encode(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encode(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent<T>(_ value: T?, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: Encodable {
        try encodeIfPresent(value, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeConditional<T>(_ object: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys1) throws where T: AnyObject, T: Encodable {
        try encodeConditional(object, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    mutating func encodeConditional<T>(_ object: T, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys2) throws where T: AnyObject, T: Encodable {
        try encodeConditional(object, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol where Key: CompoundableCodingKey {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        try decode(type, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        try decode(type, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: Key(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol where Key: CompoundableCodingKey, Key.OtherCodingKeys1: CompoundableCodingKey {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys1) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        try decode(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys2) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        try decode(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys1) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys1.OtherCodingKeys2) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys1(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol where Key: CompoundableCodingKey, Key.OtherCodingKeys2: CompoundableCodingKey {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys1) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        try decode(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys2) throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        try decode(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }

    func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys1) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys1: key))
    }

    func decodeIfPresent<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key.OtherCodingKeys2.OtherCodingKeys2) throws -> T? where T: Decodable {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: Key.OtherCodingKeys2(otherCodingKeys2: key))
    }
}
```

Then, if we change `SharedCodingKeyValues` into a `CodingKey` enum, like so:

```swift
enum SharedCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case version
    case serializer
}
```

...we can then get a container keyed by the type `CompoundCodingKeys<CodingKeys, SharedCodingKeys>`, which lets you specify *either* `Person.CodingKeys` (which does not need to be manually defined), *or* `SharedCodingKeys`, like so:

```swift
// MARK: Encodable
extension Person {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CompoundCodingKeys<CodingKeys, SharedCodingKeys>.self)

        // From `Person.CodingKeys`
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        // From `SharedCodingKeys`
        try container.encode(version, forKey: .version)
        try container.encode(serializerName, forKey: .serializer)
    }
}
```

Since `CompoundCodingKeys` itself conforms to `CodingKey`, you can even take this one step further and combine as many coding keys as you want into one, like `CompoundCodingKeys<CodingKeys, CompoundCodingKeys<SomeOtherCodingKeys, SharedCodingKeys>>`:

```swift
enum SomeOtherCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case someOtherKey
}

// MARK: Encodable
extension Person {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CompoundCodingKeys<CodingKeys, CompoundCodingKeys<SomeOtherCodingKeys, SharedCodingKeys>>.self)

        // From `Person.CodingKeys`
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)

        // From `SharedCodingKeys`
        try container.encode(version, forKey: .version)
        try container.encode(serializerName, forKey: .serializer)

        // From `SomeOtherCodingKeys`
        try container.encode(serializerName, forKey: .someOtherKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you, but do you know if your proposed solution could come in handy for this similar question i have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283127/swift-codable-dynamic-keys-as-a-subset-for-shared-properties-across-different-mo?noredirect=1#comment117187097_66283127